# SUM of a access database column in JSP?

Tags: html, database, jsp

I'm trying to get the Total SUM of a column in my MS Access database. In my JSP code, I've managed to get the values in the column, but I can't print the total SUM of the column. Please see code below. My TABLE_NAME is 'Jobs' and COLUMN_NAME I want the total SUM of is 'Order_Amount'.

```
   <sql:query dataSource="${bookdB}" var="result4">
    SELECT SUM(Order_Amount) FROM Jobs;
   </sql:query>

  <c:forEach var="column" items="${result4.rows}">
   <tr style="position:absolute; left:280px; top:277px;">    
    <td>Live Job(s) Value: <c:out value="${column.Order_Amount}"/></td> 
   </tr>
  </c:forEach>
```

Any help would be much appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: not sure if this will work, but you could try select sum(Order_Amount) as s from Jobs and them c:out value="$column.s"

Comment: Thanks for the reply, "I'm getting a {Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression" error.

Comment: not sure again :-) but I bet you that select sum() returns long and c:out somehow is expecting an int... please try Select (convert(int, sum(Order_Amount)) as s

Answer (score 0):

You have to give a name to you column in the request.

```
<sql:query dataSource="${bookdB}" var="result4">
    SELECT SUM(Order_Amount) AS theSum FROM Jobs;
</sql:query>

<c:forEach var="column" items="${result4.rows}">
   <tr style="position:absolute; left:280px; top:277px;">    
    <td>Live Job(s) Value: <c:out value="${column.theSum}"/></td> 
   </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added the code above, but I;m getting an error when compiling the page. [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression. Any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: Access displays the "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" error message when you try to sum text fields.
Make sure that "Order_Amount" is set to either the Number or Currency data type.